# Throttling of an Ideal Gas

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

$$\Delta H=\Delta (U+PV)$$
But in Ideal gas
$PV=mRT$ and $U$ is also a function of Temperature. So if throttling is an Isoenthalpic process and for an ideal gas, it's Isothermal then how do we explain the drop in Pressure?

Comment: Delta PV is zero.

Comment: Can you show how you are defining the process of throttling? /A reference where you got this idea from?

Comment: The process is about studying the temperature variation; pressure difference is maintained by ourselves.

Comment: @Bursian Ideal gas flowing through an insulated porous plug.

Comment: @ChetMiller ΔPV can't be zero in case of a flow process due to the fact that pressure drops and by conservation of mass volume can't change.

Comment: Of course the volume per mole changes in a flow process.  This does not violate conservation of mass.  What makes you think that it violates conservation of mass?

Comment: @ChetMiller do you mean the molar volume changes and subsequently density too??

Comment: Sure that is what I mean.  Molar volume is the reciprocal of molar density.   To make good on mass conservation, the gas velocity coming out of the porous plug is higher than coming in.

Comment: @ChetMiller TY. That seems a pretty good explanation. Could you please mention some literary references.

Comment: Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics, Smith & Van Ness, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, Moran et al.

Answer (score 0):

In a steady state steady flow throttling process, the specific enthalpy $h$ is constant; that is $h_i = h_o$ where $h_i$ is the specific enthalpy entering the open thermodynamic system and $h_o$ is the specific enthalpy out the open thermodynamic system. $h = u + pv$ where $u$ is the specific internal energy, $p$ is the pressure, and $v$ is the specific volume.  For an ideal gas, both $h$ and $u$ are functions of temperature alone.  Since $h$ is a function of temperature alone, there is no change in temperature of an ideal gas for a throttling process.  Since $u$ as well as $h$ is also unchanged in the throttling process, there is no change in $pv$ in the throttling process as the first comment by @Chet Miller states.  For a lower exit pressure, the decrease in pressure is compensated for by an increase in specific volume.  The process is isenthalpic, not isentropic.  For steady state steady flow, the exit velocity of the gas is greater than the inlet velocity since the specific volume of the gas increases, but for a throttling process the change in kinetic energy is very small and is ignored in the energy balance.

A throttling process is not a nozzle flow process.  For flow through a nozzle, the change in kinetic energy is not negligible and the process is close to isentropic, not isenthalpic; see the answer by @Chet Miller to [Why is a throttling valve isenthalpic whilst a nozzle is not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/656514/why-is-a-throttling-valve-isenthalpic-whilst-a-nozzle-is-not) on this exchange.

In a refrigeration/heat pump cycle, the fluid used undergoes a phase change from liquid to two phase fluid in the throttling process, and the exit temperature is significantly less than the entrance temperature.

See a good textbook on thermodynamics, such as one by Sonntag and Van Wylen.